# Preventing removal of rows in a SQL query based on ordinal position

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a collection of rows that looks something like:

```
Text  Sequence
ITEM1  1
ITEM1  2
ITEM1  3
ITEM2  4
ITEM2  5
ITEM3  6
ITEM2  7
ITEM2  8
ITEM1  9
ITEM1  10
```

I want the result to look like:

```
Text  Sequence
ITEM1  1
ITEM2  4
ITEM3  6
ITEM2  7
ITEM1  9
```

So I am taking the first instance of a row and retaining only the first sequence number however if the item is repeated further down the list i also retain the sequence number for that instance.

The SQL I have is:

```
SELECT Text,Seq=Min(Sequence)
FROM Items
GROUP BY Text
ORDER BY Seq
```

Which results in:

```
Text  Sequence
ITEM1  1
ITEM2  4
ITEM3  6
```

The GROUP BY Text statement is removing the 4th and 5th rows. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusted script to allow for gaps in Sequence

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Text char(5), Sequence int)
INSERT @t VALUES
('ITEM1',1),('ITEM1',2),('ITEM1',3),('ITEM2',4),('ITEM2',5),
('ITEM3',6),('ITEM2',7),('ITEM2',8),('ITEM1',9),('ITEM1',10)

;WITH x as
(
  SELECT Text,Sequence,
    row_number() OVER (order by Sequence)
    - row_number() OVER (partition by text order by Sequence) grp
  FROM @t
)
SELECT text, MIN(Sequence) seq
FROM x
GROUP BY text, grp
ORDER BY seq
```

Result:

```
text  seq
ITEM1 1
ITEM2 4
ITEM3 6
ITEM2 7
ITEM1 9
```

Comment: That's feels much better than the cursor. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

LAG lets you see the previous record. Compare the text with the previous line. Only show the lines where the text differs from the previous line.

```
select sequence, text
from
(
  select sequence, text, lag(text) over (order by sequence) as prev_text
  from mytable
)
where prev_text != text
or prev_text is null -- for the first line
order by sequence;
```

Comment: Thanks for this however I need to support SQL 2008 as well. Don't think LAG is supported. I'll edit my comment above to reflect

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely happy with this as I think there will be a more elegant solution however using a cursor:

```
DECLARE @text varchar(max)
DECLARE @sequence int
DECLARE @previousText varchar(max)=''
DECLARE @results TABLE (text varchar(max), sequence int)

DECLARE iterator CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Text, Sequence
FROM Items

OPEN iterator

FETCH NEXT FROM iterator
INTO @text, @sequence

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

IF(@text<>@previousText)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @results (text,sequence) VALUES (@text,@sequence)
    SET @previousText=@text
    FETCH NEXT FROM iterator INTO @text, @sequence
END
ELSE
    FETCH NEXT FROM iterator INTO @text, @sequence

CLOSE iterator
DEALLOCATE iterator

SELECT * FROM @results
```